# Change the edge color for UIButton in iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

For some reason, iOS 6 draws a standard RoundedRect differently. The old rounded button (top) has black as the edge when selected or highlighted. The same code draws the button with white as the edge in iOS 6.0 (below). I can't find a way to change the color back to Black as in iOS 5. Any idea?

The code is simply

```
_loadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[_loadButton setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 130, 115, 40)];
[_loadButton setTitle:@"Load Game" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[button.layer setBorderColor:(__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor blackColor])];
```

For rounded edges:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

You can also add this:

```
[button.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

Comment: I tried. It does show the color, but it's a rectangular black. I'm looking for rounded as in the old iOS. I think it's not possible other than a custom view...

Comment: It worked. But it wasn't the exact look of the old iOS, the color was a bit different and the border was still a bit thicker. I can live with that for now.